# Rewritten proof as edit or as comment?

Tags: support, editing

I rewrote my posted proof after someone pointed out an error and gave me a hint in the comment section. Should I edit my original post or post the rewritten proof as a comment?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral in StackExchange.  Anything of importance, esp. a correction to an answer, needs to be edited into the post.  Feel free to give credit to a Commenter if that makes sense.

Comment: I wasn't sure about editing my original question because if I eliminate the error then the comment I received wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: That is a minor tradeoff, and by crediting your Commenter for having brought an error to your attention,  you maintain some context for it.  Anyone interested can drill down in the Edit history to get details.

Comment: If editing a question or answer makes nonsense out of a comment, you can flag the comment for removal as "Obsolete" (if you have enough points to raise flags).

Answer (score 3):

The "posted proof" is an answer?  Do not do it in a comment.  You could edit the original.  Or post it as a second answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. I posted the proof as a question because I wasn't sure if it was right. So I guess posting the corrected version (giving credit to the commenter) as an answer is the way to go, right?